# Discord.py failing to send message to a specific channel in a cog/extension file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just recently started using cogs/extension files for Discord.py and ran into some issue that I don't know how to fix. I'm trying to send a message in a specific channel but I always just get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`. I know that I can send a message in a specific channel with:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("test")
  channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
  await channel.send("test2")
```

And this works perfectly fine in my "main file", but not in my "extension file", so it's not because of a wrong ID. The `await ctx.send("test")` works without problems as well, together with any other command I have, just the `channel.send` is causing troubles.

I'm importing the exact same libraries & co and otherwise should have the exact same "setup" in both files as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoneType` error means that it doesn't correctly recognize the channel. When you use `get_channel` you are looking for the channel in the bot's cache which might not have it. You could use [`fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) instead - which is an API call.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("test")
  channel = await client.fetch_channel(1234567890)
  await channel.send("test2")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I now just get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'`.

Comment: Then it's something wrong with the other part of your code. This part doesn't have any `'request'` attribute. Look for something like: `something.request` it's causing the error.

Comment: I use requests, but outside of this command. I get the error literally by just this standalone part of the code, even when I run it in a completely separate file, doesn't matter if i import requests or not. The error also occurs in the line with `channel = await client.fetch ...`

Comment: Then I would need the rest of your code to help you I can't tell what might be the problem by seeing only this part of the code.

Comment: For sure, this is the full code: https://pastebin.com/y6VMtGcE (some libraries used in other files, but they shouldn't matter. I've also removed all (in theory?) unnecessary libraries from `test.py`)

Comment: First of all, you can't create a `client` multiple times only once in the main file. Read about [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs#cogs) I think it's something you want to achieve ([your code as a cog](https://pastebin.com/3VywKr4y)). If you want to load only one simple command: [link](https://pastebin.com/9TSQGKkw), but it has many limitations - e.g. you can't use `client` I used `guild` object from `ctx` to get the channel (little workaround). In summary, try to create a Cog when you can and load commands only when it's a simple one.

Comment: I hope it's clear and helpful. If you have any questions feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the error occurs because your channel is not recognized. The solution is `fetch_channel(channel_id)`. The problem lies in your `channel = client.get_channel (1234567890)`.

Try adding `await` before client. Next replace `get_channel` with `fetch_channel`.

For general use consider your get_channel(), instead you need fetch_channel (channel_id) to retrieve an `x.GuildChannel` or `x.PrivateChannel` with the specified ID.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):

  await ctx.send("test")
  channel = await client.fetch_channel(1234567890) #update
  await channel.send("test2")
```